# Ignoring parts of search keywords?

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, codeblocks

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but is there a way to search for keywords but leave out sections that could be variable? For example I would want to search for an array element being set, but not be restricted to searching through one element at a time.

```
Foo[0] = 1;
Bar = Foo[1];
Foo[2] = 7;
```

Is there a way I could get the search to bring up "Foo[0] =" and "Foo[2] ="?

Comment: Can you provide a less abstract example?  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to match the pattern `Foo[:one or more digits:]:zero or more spaces:=:zero or more spaces:`, you can use the following regex in Sublime:

```
(Foo\[\d+\]\s*=\s*)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yF8qC6/1)